# Apache Flink: Pyflink job erroring trying to consume from Kakfka using new Flink KafkaSource API

Tags: python-3.x, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink, flink-batch

I'm trying to consumer from Kafka topic using Flink Datastream Kafka connector, described in the official documentation [here][1]

I'm using `pyflink` for Python, and running very simple example which looks like this :

```
from pyflink.common import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import KafkaSource, KafkaOffsetsInitializer
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowDeserializationSchema
from pyflink.common.watermark_strategy import WatermarkStrategy

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.add_jars("file:////home/matar/flink-1.17.0/lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.0.jar")


# Reading from Kafka
####################
row_type_info = Types.ROW_NAMED(['name', 'age'], [Types.STRING(), Types.INT()])
deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder().type_info(row_type_info).build()

source = KafkaSource.builder() \
        .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092") \
        .set_topics("quickstart-events") \
        .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
        .set_group_id("fun") \
        .set_value_only_deserializer(deserialization_schema) \
        .build()
ds = env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "kafka source").print()

env.execute()
```

I'm using Flink 1.71, and I was able to produce successfully to Kafka using the new KafkaSink API during my other tests.

The error I'm getting :

````
  File "./pyflink-examples/kafka_consumer.py", line 25, in <module>
    env.execute()
  File "/home/matar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/datastream/stream_execution_environment.py", line 764, in execute
    return JobExecutionResult(self._j_stream_execution_environment.execute(j_stream_graph))
  File "/home/matar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/home/matar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/matar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o0.execute.
: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:268)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1277)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(AkkaFutureUtils.java:47)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:300)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:297)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:221)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(AkkaFutureUtils.java:65)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:621)
        at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:24)
        at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:23)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:256)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:247)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:240)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:738)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:715)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:78)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:477)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:309)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:307)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SingleThreadFetcherManager.<init>(org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.synchronization.FutureCompletingBlockingQueue, java.util.function.Supplier, org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration, java.util.function.Consumer)'
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.fetcher.KafkaSourceFetcherManager.<init>(KafkaSourceFetcherManager.java:72)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource.createReader(KafkaSource.java:163)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource.createReader(KafkaSource.java:135)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.initReader(SourceOperator.java:286)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask.init(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:94)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:692)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:669)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:904)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)```

  [1]: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#kafka-source
````